# How to save and restore the state of a random number generator with CUDA CURAND?

Tags: python, c++, numpy, cuda

I am using a large CUDA-matrix library developed within our organization. I need to save the state of a CUDA RNG to take a snapshop of a long-running simulation, and be able to restore it later. This is simple with, e.g., python+numpy:

```
state = numpy.random.get_state()
# state is a tuple with 5 fields which can be pickled, etc.
...
numpy.random.set_state(state)
```

I cannot seem to find equivalent functionality in the CUDA host api. You can set the seed and offset, but there is no way to retrieve it to save. The device API seems to offer something like this, but this library uses the host api, and it would be monsterous to change.

The hack-ey solution I am thinking about is to keep track of the number of calls to the RNG (reset when a seed is set), and simply call a RNG function repeatedly. However, I am not sure if the function parameters must be identical, e.g. matrix shapes, etc., to get it to the same state. Similarly, if the number of calls was equivalent to the offset parameter for initializing the RNG, this would work as well, i.e., if I call the RNG 200 times, I could set the offset to 200. However, in python, the offset in the state can increase by more than 1 with each call, so this is also potentially wrong.

Any insights into how to tackle this are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For the CURAND Host API, I believe [curandSetGeneratorOffset()](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/group__HOST.html#group__HOST_1gb21ba987f85486e552797206451b0939) can probably work for this.

Here's a modified example from the curand host API documentation:

```
$ cat t721.cu
/*
 * This program uses the host CURAND API to generate 10
 * pseudorandom floats.  And then regenerate those same floats.
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <curand.h>

#define CUDA_CALL(x) do { if((x)!=cudaSuccess) { \
    printf("Error at %s:%d\n",__FILE__,__LINE__);\
    return EXIT_FAILURE;}} while(0)
#define CURAND_CALL(x) do { if((x)!=CURAND_STATUS_SUCCESS) { \
    printf("Error at %s:%d\n",__FILE__,__LINE__);\
    return EXIT_FAILURE;}} while(0)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    size_t n = 10;
    size_t i;
    curandGenerator_t gen;
    float *devData, *hostData;

    /* Allocate n floats on host */
    hostData = (float *)calloc(n, sizeof(float));

    /* Allocate n floats on device */
    CUDA_CALL(cudaMalloc((void **)&devData, n*sizeof(float)));

    /* Create pseudo-random number generator */
    CURAND_CALL(curandCreateGenerator(&gen,
                CURAND_RNG_PSEUDO_DEFAULT));

    /* Set seed */
    CURAND_CALL(curandSetPseudoRandomGeneratorSeed(gen,
                1234ULL));
    // generator offset = 0
    /* Generate n floats on device */
    CURAND_CALL(curandGenerateUniform(gen, devData, n));
    // generator offset = n
    /* Generate n floats on device */
    CURAND_CALL(curandGenerateUniform(gen, devData, n));
    // generator offset = 2n
    /* Copy device memory to host */
    CUDA_CALL(cudaMemcpy(hostData, devData, n * sizeof(float),
        cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    /* Show result */
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%1.4f ", hostData[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    CURAND_CALL(curandSetGeneratorOffset(gen, n));
    // generator offset = n
    CURAND_CALL(curandGenerateUniform(gen, devData, n));
    // generator offset = 2n
    /* Copy device memory to host */
    CUDA_CALL(cudaMemcpy(hostData, devData, n * sizeof(float),
        cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    /* Show result */
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%1.4f ", hostData[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");



    /* Cleanup */
    CURAND_CALL(curandDestroyGenerator(gen));
    CUDA_CALL(cudaFree(devData));
    free(hostData);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
$ nvcc -o t721 t721.cu -lcurand
$ ./t721
0.7816 0.2338 0.6791 0.2824 0.6299 0.1212 0.4333 0.3831 0.5136 0.2987

0.7816 0.2338 0.6791 0.2824 0.6299 0.1212 0.4333 0.3831 0.5136 0.2987
$
```

So you'll need to keep track of the quantity of random numbers generated (*not* the number of RNG function calls) up to the point when you do your checkpoint, and save that.

When you restart, initialize the generator in the same way:

```
    /* Create pseudo-random number generator */
    CURAND_CALL(curandCreateGenerator(&gen,
                CURAND_RNG_PSEUDO_DEFAULT));

    /* Set seed */
    CURAND_CALL(curandSetPseudoRandomGeneratorSeed(gen,
                1234ULL));
```

but then advance by the number of previously generated values (`n`):

```
    CURAND_CALL(curandSetGeneratorOffset(gen, n));
```

Comment: Ahh, I see. So if I generate a matrix with 100 elements, update the offset by 100. I guess what is throwing me off is the comparison to numpy.random. If I do np.random.rand(1,1), it advances the offset by 2, or rand(3,7) advances by 42 instead of 21. There is nothing in the CUDA docs that explain how the offset advances. So, it looks like I will have to do some digging and brute force testing to ensure I can generate the correct values for a given offset. I'll report back with an answer when I have it, hopefully today.

Comment: I wouldn't try to infer behavior of the CURAND api based on behavior of numpy.  And yes, at this time keeping track of the quantity of numbers generated is the only way I know of to restart the curand HOST api to a specific place in the generation sequence.

Comment: I agree re. numpy. It was more meant to inform my understanding of pitfalls with RNGs in general. It turns out that both CUDA and numpy generate 4-bytes, and the numpy default is float64, hence the offset increment of 2. CUDA seems to behave the same way.

My first pass at this is not working, i.e. setting the offset manually based on the number of values generated does not produce the same sequence. I have found that our library actually uses curand_init in addition to the host API, so I am determining if I need to pass the offset to curand_init in addition to or in lieu of setGeneratorOffset

Answer (score 0):

So, it is possible to store and restore the state by tracking the number of 32-bit values generated using curandSetGeneratorOffset. The algorithm looks something like:

```
template<typename T> RNG(T* X, size_T N /*number of values*/){
...

if (sizeof(T) == 1)
    offset += (N+4-1)/4;
else if (sizeof(T) == 2)
    offset += (N+2-1)/4;
else if (sizeof(T) == 4 || USING_GENERATE_UNIFORM_DOUBLE)
    offset += N;
else if (sizeof(T) == 8)
    offset += 2*N;
}
```

For 8-bit values, advance the offset by the N * next highest multiple of 4, for N values generated. For 16, advance by N * the next multiple of 2. For 32 advance by the N, and for 64 advance by 2*N.

HOWEVER, if you use GenerateUniformDouble, you only need to advance by N, not 2*N. I'm not sure why.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: there are no [CURAND host API functions](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/group__HOST.html#group__HOST) that generate 8 or 16 bit quantities. Not sure why you need all this arithmetic.  The number of quantities generated, whether they are 32 or 64 bit, is the number you need to keep track of.  If you are generating a 32 bit random number and somehow jamming it into an 8 bit quantity, that's pretty much irrelevant.  And certainly `RNG` is not part of CURAND, so this arithmetic probably only makes sense for some specific function of yours.

Comment: The count of raw PRNG results consumed is not necessarily in a 1:1 relationship with the count of pseudo random numbers returned at the user-visible interface. Distributions other than uniform, or wide data types may require multiple raw results to produce a single finished random number. The ratio raw:finished may not even be constant if rejection algorithms are used for some of the more complex distributions. The problem is not unique to CURAND, but generally one of parallel PRNGs. I am not aware of a standard solution (pointers welcome).